# How to get Client machine time on server on pageload event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use client system date on page load event,
How can I do that.

Since this is not a post back so please let me know how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = new Date()
```

The currentDate object will have the methods:

```
getMonth()
getDate()
getFullYear()
```

This should give you what you need.

Edit:

Since you mentioned time in the title of the post, it's probably worth mentioning that currentDate will also have:

```
getHours()
getMinutes()
```

should you want to display the current time as well.

Edit 2:

To tie into page loading

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function buildDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    /*build date string here*/
  }
</script>

<body onload="buildDate()">
Other stuff here...
</body>
```

Comment: I want to fetch todays report on page load but as I am passing server side date so when the timezone changes then I am unable to see some records.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "&date=" + (new Date().replace(/\s+/g, ""));
```

Just append the value of a to all your links back to the server.  On the serverside you will see the datetime come across in the HTTP request.